# SQL: Getting day specific totals when totals are summed per week

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the first time I'm asking something on this site, so if this question was asked badly, I would appreciate the feedback.

So the problem is the following. 
In my Table, let's call it "Totals", i have totals of sales. Every row has the complete total of that week, along with the individual totals of each day of the week. So those five totals add up to the weektotal. 
Every row also has the week of the year in it (format: yyyyww).

so it would look like this for example

```sql
id|date  |total|totalsu|totalmo|totaltu|totalwe|totalth|totalfr|totalsa
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1|201921| 50.0| 00.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 0.0  |
 2|201922| 60.0| 00.0  | 15.0  | 10.0  | 15.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 0.0  |
 3|201923| 70.0| 30.0  |  5.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  |  5.0  | 0.0  |
 4|201924| 50.0| 00.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 10.0  | 0.0  |
```

Now my question is, how would i get all of the totals from  let's say wednesday in the week 201921 to tuesday in the week 201924 within one query? It would be great if I could get it within one query, but if it's absolutely impossible, two or three should be fine as well.
The expected output would be 180 if my math is correct.

Comment: This is a rather wierd table you have there, why are the days split on columns and not rows ?

Comment: That's a very good question. I don't know. It's a very very old table and i'm new with this company. Looks like we're just going to have to accept it.

Comment: What would be the query criterias, would it be like two dates, or two year-week (what's in your date column) and two days ?

Comment: Right, I forgot to say: The criteria would be two normal dates. I generate the Query with the Delphi programming language, where i have two normal dates and i need to make one (preferably) query with those two dates. But you don't need to write delphi code for me, just give me an SQL example of wednesday to tuesday 2 weeks later.

I hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this, although there might be more efficient/clean ones, is to make use of [CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html) statments. You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    sum(
        CASE WHEN date < YEARWEEK($startDate, 0) OR date > YEARWEEK($endDate, 0) THEN 0
        WHEN date = YEARWEEK($startDate, 0) THEN
            CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK($startDate) = 1 THEN totalsu + totalmo + totaltu + totalwe + totalth + totalfr + totalsa
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($startDate) = 2 THEN totalmo + totaltu + totalwe + totalth + totalfr + totalsa
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($startDate) = 3 THEN totaltu + totalwe + totalth + totalfr + totalsa
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($startDate) = 4 THEN totalwe + totalth + totalfr + totalsa
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($startDate) = 5 THEN totalth + totalfr + totalsa
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($startDate) = 6 THEN totalfr + totalsa
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($startDate) = 7 THEN totalsa
            END
        WHEN date = YEARWEEK($endDate, 0) THEN
            CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK($endDate) = 7 THEN totalsu + totalmo + totaltu + totalwe + totalth + totalfr + totalsa
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($endDate) = 6 THEN totalsu + totalmo + totaltu + totalwe + totalth + totalfr
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($endDate) = 5 THEN totalsu + totalmo + totaltu + totalwe + totalth
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($endDate) = 4 THEN totalsu + totalmo + totaltu + totalwe
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($endDate) = 3 THEN totalsu + totalmo + totaltu
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($endDate) = 2 THEN totalsu + totalmo
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK($endDate) = 1 THEN totalsu
            END
        WHEN date > YEARWEEK($startDate, 0) OR date < YEARWEEK($endDate, 0) THEN totalsu + totalmo + totaltu + totalwe + totalth + totalfr + totalsa
        END
    )
FROM
    table;
```

I am not 100% sure about the syntax, but it should provide the expected result or give you a way to go to get them. I used the [YEARWEEK](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_mysql_yearweek.asp) and [DAYOFWEEK](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php) functions.

Comment: Instead of writing `totalsu + totalmo + ... + totalsa`, couldn't you also have just written `total`?